# CMAKE_ How can I evaluate the current line where a cmake function is invoked?

Tags: cmake

For debugging purposes, it would be nice if I can access

1. the file name of the script
2. the current line number in the script

at **configure time** where a CMake function/macro was **invoked**. (I want to inject this information automatically via wrapper functions for my own component to track when and where cache variables were overwritten).

While 1. seems to be working with evaluating CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE, I cannot figure out how to achieve 2. [CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_LINE](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_LINE.html) is always set to the line where it is actually placed, in my case the line inside the wrapper function.

As suggested [in the CMake bugtracker](http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=14118#c32947), I could do it on caller site with passing [CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_LINE][3] as additional argument. But I would like to avoid that to hide the debugging logic from the "public interface".

---

A minimal working example to express what I want:

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
include( myComponent )

# access via public interface
myComponentFunctionWrapperFunction( "CMakeLists.txt:5" )
myComponentFunctionWrapperMacro( "CMakeLists.txt:6" )
myComponentMacroWrapperFunction( "CMakeLists.txt:7" )
myComponentMacroWrapperMacro( "CMakeLists.txt:8" )

# direct access of the hidden interface
myComponentFunction( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_LINE} "CMakeLists.txt:11" )
myComponentFunction( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_LINE} "CMakeLists.txt:12" )
myComponentMacro( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_LINE} "CMakeLists.txt:13" )
myComponentMacro( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_LINE} "CMakeLists.txt:14" )
```

**myComponent.cmake**:

```
# the actual component

function( myComponentFunction CALLER CALLER_LINE DATA )
    message( STATUS "myComponent.function( ${CALLER}, ${CALLER_LINE}, ${DATA} )" )
endfunction()

macro( myComponentMacro CALLER CALLER_LINE DATA )
    message( STATUS "myComponent.macro( ${CALLER}, ${CALLER_LINE}, ${DATA} )" )
endmacro()


# the public interface for injecting debug info

function( myComponentFunctionWrapperFunction DATA )
    myComponentFunction( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_LINE} ${DATA} )
endfunction()

macro( myComponentFunctionWrapperMacro DATA )
    myComponentFunction( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_LINE} ${DATA} )
endmacro()

function( myComponentMacroWrapperFunction DATA )
    myComponentMacro( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_LINE} ${DATA} )
endfunction()

macro( myComponentMacroWrapperMacro DATA )
    myComponentMacro( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_LINE} ${DATA} )
endmacro()
```

**Execution**:

```
$ cmake -D CMAKE_MODULE_PATH=`pwd` .
-- myComponent.function( <myPath>/CMakeLists.txt, 15, CMakeLists.txt:5 )
-- myComponent.function( <myPath>/CMakeLists.txt, 19, CMakeLists.txt:6 )
-- myComponent.macro( <myPath>/CMakeLists.txt, 23, CMakeLists.txt:7 )
-- myComponent.macro( <myPath>/CMakeLists.txt, 27, CMakeLists.txt:8 )
-- myComponent.function( <myPath>/CMakeLists.txt, 11, CMakeLists.txt:11 )
-- myComponent.function( <myPath>/CMakeLists.txt, 12, CMakeLists.txt:12 )
-- myComponent.macro( <myPath>/CMakeLists.txt, 13, CMakeLists.txt:13 )
-- myComponent.macro( <myPath>/CMakeLists.txt, 14, CMakeLists.txt:14 )
-- Configuring done
```

---

Maybe I can access the stack trace somehow? If you issue, e.g., message( WARNING ...) the line numbers are available. But I want to store them, not just print it on the terminal.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is possible.

> I want to inject this information automatically via wrapper functions
>   for my own component to track when and where cache variables were
>   overwritten)

Have you tried using cmake with --trace (or even --trace-expand if you have an recent enough CMake version) ? It may be a better way to achieve your goal

Answer (score 0):

try below
message(STATUS, " [Line ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_LINE}]:")